# Null and Empty List Check in Java 8

Tags: java, java-8

I want to write an equivalent code for  this using Java 8 features of Streams or Optional
My idea is basically to check if the List has some value returned from a Query or null /empty

```
if (resultList != null && resultList.size() > 0) {
    retVal = true;
}
```

Comment: `resultList != null && !resultList.isEmpty()`

Comment: I strongly advise you to make sure a list is never `null`, if you can. It should be empty in such case.

Comment: @MCEmperor I agree, but I have come across some cases when deserializing (XML wiht JAXB, JSON with Jackson) that had a default behavior of not initializing a member if the field was not present in the incoming data, and you had to jump through some ugly hoops to enforce this.

Comment: @MCEmperor That's often a good idea, but wasteful of memory if you have a `Map<K, List<V>>` with hundreds of thousands of keys associated with empty lists.

Comment: @kaya3 Hundreds of thousands of keys associated with the same empty list instance (such as `Collections.emptyList()`) do not need any more memory than hundreds of thousands of keys associated with `null`. But why not leave these keys out of the Map altogether, and do `map.getOrDefault(key, emptyList)` ?

Comment: @kaya3 Well in that case, setting a mapping with a `null` value would mean that you don't map the key at all (some `Map` implementations don't even allow `map.put(key, null)`).

Comment: @Thilo But then when you want to add something to one of those lists, you need to check if it's a `Collections.emptyList()` and replace it with a fresh mutable list, rather than just doing `computeIfAbsent`. And of course you save the memory by not having those keys in the map at all.

Comment: @daniu Yes, precisely; so when you do `List<V> values = map.get(key);` then you will have to check if `values != null` before using it. That's the point I'm making.

Comment: ah... Don't get me started on mutable lists :-)

Answer (score 0):

```java
retVal = Optional.ofNullable(resultList).filter(l -> !l.isEmpty()).isPresent();
```

Comment: or just `retVal = resultList != null && !resultList.isEmpty()`

Comment: I know, but the question was how to do that "using Java 8 features of Streams or Optional"

Comment: And the proper answer to that is: Don't, there is no need for it.

Answer (score 0):

Avoid null.

```
return resultList == null ? Collections.emptyList() : resultList;
```

And then check the list with `list.isEmpty()`.

`Optional` is redundant and more or less functions as a collection of 0/1 elements, as unpacking is needed, and then one still has a collection.

One might sometimes consider returning a Stream, if the result must be requeried every time.

```
return result == null ? Stream.empty() : resultList.stream();
```